# Nginx Fails with [emrg] error

Tags: linux, webserver, nginx, digital-ocean

My web app has failed to load after I tried uploading some of my folders with `Filezilla`. On inspection of the problem, I found that `Nginx` service isn't running.

The result of `sudo nginx -t` is:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "LISTEN" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:22
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Now I open up the `default` file with `vi` and on the line 22 there's a bunch of comments with nothing related to the specified `LISTEN` Nginx warned about. I don't really know where else to look for the **`LISTEN`**.

This question is pretty close to what I may be experiencing, but the answers there are not exactly helpful. -> [nginx-configuration-failed](https://superuser.com/questions/1490594/nginx-configuration-failed)

#### Here is the content of `default`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sajjalbank.com www.sajjalbank.com;
  # return 301 https://sajjalbank.com$request_uri;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://sajjalbank.com/$1 permanent;
}


##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {

    ###     listen 80 default_server;
    ###     listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 443 ssl;


        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        ###root /var/www/html;
        root /home/sajjal/sajjal/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    ###  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        ###server_name sajjalbank.com www.sajjalbank.com;
        server_name _;
        ssl_certificate /home/myssl/sajjalbank.com_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/myssl/sajjalbank.com.key;

        ###ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ### ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ### ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';


        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

What is wrong with this file?

Comment: Forgive me, but if I am not mistaken, it is throwing error with `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.save:22`, not `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Comment: It seemed the `default.save` was hidden, once I saw it, I completed deleted it. `nginx -t` works normal now, but there are other issues am currently battling to fix for the site to come back up.